# Is it possible to access the Desktop view to draw it to PDF?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I have an app that I want to make Mac App Store screenshots for. It's a menubar app so taking a regular screenshot leads to really low resolution images. I have figured out how to screenshot my app's views to a PDF, and then convert the PDF to SVG, and then SVG to PNG. It's a bit of a round about way to get screenshots, but it works, and they can be made in high resolution which is what I want. My question is, is there anyway to do a similar thing but with the desktop of my computer? I basically want to take a screenshot of the desktop view, and write it to a PDF, same as I do for my app's views.

Here's how I currently do it for my own app's views.

This is a function on my NSPopover subclass, so that's where `contentViewController!.view` is coming from.

```swift
let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)).pdf") as CFURL
let size = Defaults[.windowSize]
var mediaBox = NSRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
let gc = CGContext(url, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil)!
let nsgc = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: gc, flipped: false)
NSGraphicsContext.current = nsgc
gc.beginPDFPage(nil); do {
  let view = contentViewController!.view as! NSHostingView<ContentView>
  gc.saveGState(); do {
    gc.drawFlipped(rect: mediaBox) {
      view.layer?.render(in: gc)
    }
  }; gc.restoreGState()

}; gc.endPDFPage()
NSGraphicsContext.current = nil
gc.closePDF()
```

I basically want to know if there's someway to replace `contentViewController!.view` with something that accesses the desktop view(with the menu bar ideally.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of writing it to PDF, or why "a menubar app so taking a regular screenshot leads to really low resolution images", but ScreenCaptureKit now includes APIs for getting screenshots (of either your app or others, including the Desktop)

Comment: @jnpdx The purpose of writing it to PDF is that I get a vector image. The reason the menu app has lower resolution images is because the window is small, not full screen. So if I open the app, and take a screenshot of my screen, the app itself is only about 5-10% of the screen. If I then enlarge it in order to show things more clearly in the app store images, the resolution is now very low. With a PDF vector image, I can make it the size of the empire state building and it'll still be sharp.

Comment: You can't get a bitmap of the Mac desktop (or any bitmap for that matter) and convert it to a vector somehow -- the best you'll get is a bitmap written into a PDF

Comment: I don't want a bitmap converted to a vector, i'd ideally like the original vector, same as I have for my app screenshots. They are not converted to vector, they are drawn to PDF as vector, by AppKit.

Comment: You cannot get a vector of the Mac desktop.

Comment: @jnpdx Why not? It's a view isn't it? I can get vectors from other views, so presumably if I can access that view, I can create a vector from it. if it's not possible to access the desktop view, that's another thing, but to say I cannot get a vector from a view is wrong, because the code I included already does that, turns views to vector files

Comment: No, the desktop isn't just "a view". Plus, it's not owned by your app, so you have no access to any underlying NSView. The APIs (both ScreenCaptureKit and CoreGraphics as referenced in the answer below) return a _bitmap_ image. Even if you did have access to the NSView, the literal desktop image is a bitmap and wouldn't be vectorized.

Comment: @jnpdx gotcha, that makes sense. It's mainly the menubar that I want to get a vector of, since I can replace the actual desktop image with another image in the mockups, if needed. Is it possible to access the menubar view, or is that also not possible?

Comment: Unlikely, since the menubar contains quite a bit that your app doesn't own, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [How to increase the size of the OS X user interface without lowering the resolution?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45716/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-os-x-user-interface-without-lowering-the-resolut)

Comment: @PeterR Consider that at bottom, desktop wallpapers are just large (rasterized photos). Even if you _could_ get a PDF capture of it, it would just be a vectorized file that embeds a bitmap layer for the desktop wall paper. Many other icons (e.g. all App icons), are also the same. I think your best best is to set the largest possible screen scaling, and take a regular ol' screenshot of that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this couldn't work in you, but i'm hoping it is. So by doing that, use the `CGWindowListCreateImage` function from the Core Graphics framework. This function creates an image of the specified window.

Example:

```
let windowListOption = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: .optionIncludingWindow)
let windowID = CGWindowID(yourWindow.windowNumber)
let imageOption = CGWindowImageOption(arrayLiteral: .boundsIgnoreFraming)

let image = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRect.null, windowListOption, windowID, imageOption)
```

In the above code, `yourWindow` is the window you want to capture. You can get it from a `NSWindow` instance. The `CGWindowListCreateImage` function returns a `CGImage` that you can then draw in your context.

If you want to capture the entire screen, including the menu bar, you can use the `NSBitmapImageRep` class to create a bitmap representation of the screen and then draw it in your context.

Example for that is:

```
let screenRect = NSScreen.main!.frame
let bitmap = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil, pixelsWide: Int(screenRect.width), pixelsHigh: Int(screenRect.height), bitsPerSample: 8, samplesPerPixel: 4, hasAlpha: true, isPlanar: false, colorSpaceName: .calibratedRGB, bytesPerRow: 0, bitsPerPixel: 0)!

let context = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: bitmap)!
NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
NSGraphicsContext.current = context

yourWindow.contentView!.draw(screenRect)

NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()
```

`yourWindow` is the window you want to capture. The `draw` method of `NSView` draws the view in the specified rectangle of the destination. You can then use the `bitmap` to create an image and draw it in your context.

*This methods will not capture the content of windows that are not owned by your application due to sandboxing restrictions. Also, capturing the menu bar is not possible as it is a separate process and cannot be captured by an application.

Comment: These are deprecated APIs, but they do still work. For a high-resolution image, you should include the `bestResolution` flag on `CGWindowListCreateImage`

Comment: Thank you, I think that also, but since im no longer using this, i'm sorry that I couldn't help accurately.